# How can I find optimal values for training arguments?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

These are the training arguments for a text classification bert model. (I'm using huggingface trainer)
I need to find the optimal values of `training epochs`, `batch size`, `learning rate`, `warmup steps`, `weight decay` for my dataset. Is there any way to check them before training?

Are there other arguments that I should consider?

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    learning_rate= 5e-05
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    logging_steps=400,         
    save_steps=400,            
    evaluation_strategy="steps",     
)
```

Comment: Basically you train with different parameters and see what works best: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization

Comment: If you really want to find a good combination of hyperparameters, you can try bayesian hyperparameter tuning which can help you find it quickly compare to greedy grid search. Weight & bias supports this kind of hyperparameter search https://wandb.ai/site/articles/bayesian-hyperparameter-optimization-a-primer .

Comment: but in general, in my experience, the learning rate might be the most important one for finetuning pre-trained models.

Answer (score -1):

On one hand the optimal parameters to those depend on the size of your training data and may be also slightly on the number of the classes you have. On the other hand it depends highly on the hardware you are using. So far I know, the only way of checking it beforehand is to know the algorithm and calculate theoretically what would work the best.

I would set the number of the epochs higher.

If you use GPUs, which I would recommend, one additional parameter called gradient accumulation can help you to speed up the training significantly, like:

gradient_accumulation_steps=32

Comment: Actually, `gradient_accumulation_steps` slow down the training, but it allows you to pass a bigger `batch_size_per_device` and it helps to get a better result (batch size matters!). You can check more about `gradient_accumulation_steps` and other performance optimizations [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/performance#gradient-accumulation) .